# SFTP equivalent of HTTP URL

Tags: url, authentication, https, sftp

What can be the URL of SFTP equivalent of the following HTTP URL:

> https://myftp.example.com/FolderName/FileName.csv

Also, my SFTP URL will be authenticated with following User Credentials:

- Username: User1
- Password: Pass1

I tried the following URL:

> sftp://User1:Pass1@myftp.example.com:22/FolderName/FileName.csv

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing how the web server has been configured.

Comment: 1) Where do you want to use the SFTP URL? 2) The SFTP is typically used to access remote file system. Mapping between file system paths and web paths is done by HTTP server. We cannot know what the mapping on your server is. 3) There's no standard for SFTP URLs anyway.

Comment: The hostname for SFTP URL can be different than the hostname for HTTP URL. Again, we cannot know that.

Comment: We are going to access this URL from a .Net application. There is a file named FileName1.csv and we would like to download that csv on hitting that SFTP URL

Comment: How are you *going to access this URL from a .Net application*? Why do you want to download it using SFTP, if you can download it using HTTPS?

Comment: I want to download a CSV file from a particular folder structure on SFTP server. I am going to access it using WinSCP.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax

To specify a relative path from the user's home directory

```
sftp://[user:password@]host[:port]/~/URI[?queryParameters]
```

To specify an absolute path from the root directory

```
sftp://[user:password@]host[:port]/URI[?queryParameters]
```

To specify a path that represents a directory

```
sftp://[user:password@]host[:port]/~/path/;type=d
```

Attributes

**sftp**

Indicates the required protocol identifier.

**user**

Optionally specifies a user ID on the target host. If omitted, specify the user ID for authentication in the SFTP client policy of the user agent. You must encode the following characters: @ / :

**password**

Optionally specifies the password corresponding to the user ID. If omitted, specify the user password for authentication in the SFTP client policy of the user agent. You must encode the following characters: @ / :

**host**

Fully qualified domain name or IP address of the target host.

**port**

Optionally identifies the connection port on the host. If omitted, the default value is 22.

**URI**

For a PUT (write) operation, specifies the remote location that receives the file. The URI for a GET (read) operation specifies the location from which the element fetches the file.

**queryParameters**

Specifies name-value pairs that follow the URI. Use a question mark (?) after the URI but before the first query parameter.

**Delete**

Indicates a request to delete the file that is specified by the URI. The default value is false.

false
Does not delete the file.
true
Deletes the file that is specified by the URI. Meaningful only for a read operation, that is, only if no data is provided with the request.